# Do I need to protect the settings fields of a parallel sorting algorithm with mutex?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, mutex

I aim towards the following design:

```
public final class MyArrays {
    private static int insertionsortThreshold = 10;
    private static int mergesortThreshold = 400;

    public static void setInsertionsortThreshold(int value) {
        insertionsortThreshold = value;
    }

    public static void setMergesortThreshold(int value) {
        mergesortThreshold = value;
    }

    public static void parallelSort(int[] array) {
        // Relies on insertionsortThreshold and mergesortThreshold.
    }
}
```

My question is: do I need to protect `insertionsortThreshold` and `mergesortThreshold` with a mutex?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to protect those values if you expect them to change during the runtime of the parallel part. If those values are set only once and then kept constant, then you do not need a mutex to synchronize access to it during the parallel computation, but you will need to make the `set` methods `synchronized` to make sure that their values are visible to all threads when work starts.

If you *do* expect to change the thresholds during parallel execution, then you need a mutex (at the very least) to make sure that things work well. I'd actually suggest using a `ReentrantReadWriteLock` since you can safely have multiple read-only accesses, and only really need to synchronize when a write is happening.

Comment: Actually, it appears to me that reentrant lock is not suitable since it will be called pretty often.

Comment: So my idea was to lock the mutex once for entire computation of the parallel sort.

Comment: @coderodde whether or not that is a good idea depends on how long you are willing to wait for a `parallelSort` to complete. Keep in mind that with this you can only have one parallel sort happening at a time for all `MyArrays` instances because the thresholds you are using are static. This is quite a restriction in your design.